# Rotor replacement/machining necessary after car has been sitting for a couple of months!

Tags: brakes, mazda, brake-rotor, rust, corrosion

My 2013 Mazda CX-5 has been sitting out for a couple of months and we had a pretty wet spring here. When I took it in for service, the dealership told me that they want to replace the rear rotors and machine the front ones due to corrosion.

I did notice a bit of a crunchy sound when driving for the first time but was expecting that to just go away after braking a few times.

Here are the pictures that the dealership sent me:

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate any thoughts on whether replacing/machining the rotors is reasonable. The pads are still good.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the dealer has measured them, even though most of the corrosion has now gone, they may be too thin and need replacing.

Given rotors are cheaper than the consequences of brakes failing, I would put the news ones on. And have just done so on all 4 corners of my car.